# How to concatenate 2 numbers using dot using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a EmployeeAudit table like below :

```
Id      EmployeeId      
1       100
2       101
```

I have a 2 below variable:

```
DECLARE @Version INT = 10;
DECLARE @isAuditDone BIT = 0;
//logic to populate Version and isAuditDone
```

Based on above variable, I want to check if Audit is done then I want to return Id from EmployeeAudit like below :

```
if @isAuditDone
    return Id + '.' + Version = 1.10
else 
    return Id
```

Query:

```
select 
    (CASE
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 1
                THEN E.Id + '.' + @Version
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 0
                THEN E.Id
          ELSE 
                E.Id
          END) AS Id, 
          EmployeeId
    from 
    EmployeeAudit E
```

But I am getting below error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type
> int.

Can someone please help?

Update :

EXEC [dbo].[GetEmployeeAuditJson]
@employeeId = 101

SP return type on `select statement`:

```
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES;
```

Comment: Is this code in a stored procedure? You can't _return_ a string from a stored procedure, return is used for status / error codes, and it only supports `int`. Also `return Id + '.' + Version = 1.10` doesn't flow. Try `SELECT CONCAT(Id, '.', @Version);`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the suggestion. I tried what you suggested but still getting the error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.10' to data type int. This code is in a Stored Procedure

Comment: Can you show the _actual code_ you're using because the code in your question doesn't compile for me. If you're still trying to use `return` you're never going to be able to `return` a string from a stored procedure. `CONCAT` ignores types, so should let you build a string without dealing with conversion errors. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8dd86cf7cf5f5bbba0923ae081236ab). But you're going to have to use a `SELECT` or an `OUTPUT` parameter, because a stored procedure can't `return` a value like `5.1.10`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thats the actual code I have posted in the question. What error you are getting ? What is the solution to return output as "1.10" ? There is no solution for this?

Comment: What is the stored procedure definition you are using and how you are executing stored proc, can you describe that ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am using select to return the output and this is mentioned in the end : FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

Comment: @magnus Updated my question to reflect your ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on Aaron's comment

You'll need to keep the data type consistent.  In this case strings.

```
select 
    (CASE
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 1
                THEN concat(E.Id,'.',@Version)
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 0
                THEN concat('',E.Id)  -- Notice INT to string 
          ELSE 
                concat('',E.Id)       -- Notice INT to string 
          END) AS Id, 
          EmployeeId
    from 
    EmployeeAudit E
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Let me try this. Also, is it possible to return it as 1.10 as decimal or float if isAuditDone = 1 else return int if isAuditDone = 0 if we have a problem returning string as mentioned by others?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Sure, you can wrap the CASE in a convert(decimal(2), case ... ) as ID

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow The take away here is that the datatype of the CASE expression has to be consistent...  int, string, decimal,  etc.

Comment: Do you think string would be good idea for this data or decimal? Any suggestion please? I will really appreciate

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow My first choice would be a string.  No 0 decimals and may also have the ability to include alpha characters  1 ... 1.00  ... 1a  ... 1a.25

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return something other than integer value from Stored Procedure then you need to use Output column.
So in your case you have to return String as you have a Dot to append with number.
This is a demo stored procedure definition you can try using to fulfil what you desire.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  SProc
@Id varchar(500) OUTPUT
AS 
select 
    (CASE
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 1
                THEN concat(E.Id,'.',@Version)
          WHEN @isAuditDone = 0
                THEN concat('',E.Id)   
          ELSE 
                concat('',E.Id)       
          END) AS Id, 
          EmployeeId
    from 
    EmployeeAudit E
```

You can then execute your stored proc like this with output parameter.

```
Declare @Id varchar(500)
EXEC SProc  @Id  OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but see my update. Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me though